# connect to Bloomberg from R

Tags: r, bloomberg

I receive the error:

```
Error in .jnew("org/findata/blpwrapper/Connection", java.log.level) : 
  org.findata.blpwrapper.WrapperException: Session not started because: Failed to connect server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8194
```

when I run the command blpConnect()  on R 2.15.0

that is the whole output:

```
> blpConnect()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30) 
rJava Version 0.9-3 
Rbbg Version 0.4-153 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Error in .jnew("org/findata/blpwrapper/Connection", java.log.level) : 
  org.findata.blpwrapper.WrapperException: Session not started because: Failed to connect server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8194
```

I don't know what that means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running this on a machine with a Bloomberg terminal installed and logged in? is the bbcom.exe process running?

Comment: Even on a BBG computer make sure to install the J API via WAPI<GO><GO> first.

Comment: Thank you Hansi. Re-installing the J API fixed the problem.